# what to use in updating state in vue.js Application (rxJs vs Vuex)

Tags: angular, vue.js, rxjs, vuex

I'm new to vue.js but I have dabbled in angular 6 for a year now. I used to update data in the components in Angular by using RxJs which I found very easy. Now when I came across Vue, veux popped up in articles on updating the state of components. Which one is better in updating the state of a component?

is it better to use vuex state Management to update state or using reactive programming with rxJs?

```
// angular
import { AppService } from '../AppService';
isLoading = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.appService.updateIsLoading.subscribe((res: boolean) => {
  this.isLoading = res;
});
}

// Vue
const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      isLoading: false,
  }
});.....................
```

Answer (score 8):

**Vuex and rxJs solve different problems.**

**Vuex** manages your shared state, similar to redux or ngrx in the angular world. State is stored 'centrally', outside of visual components, and your state management solution provides things like time travel, consistent access and a bit of functional discipline. Ngrx is not an official part of the angular framework.

**rxJs** wraps your asynchronous code as observables, providing a different, more powerful syntax for asynchronous operations, but there's a learning curve. Angular loves rxJs and it's a core part of the platform. The Vue world seems not to love it so much and you can certainly do without. But if you're coming from somewhere else and you know what you like, go for it. Angular tutorials will talk about rxJs as a state management solution, but it is doing a fundamentally different job, and should be considered alongside promises and async/await, rather than "state management" as it's understood in react and vue.

Comment: You can still use rxjs to manage state

Comment: This is still a question for me. I've worked on quite large angular apps. I've only seen rxjs used as a wrapper for http calls (one shot), and a pretty unfriendly one at that. State was "managed" by putting it in a service. I suspect "managing state" with rxjs means "make it someone else's problem".